# `path` does not exist: ‘’ in c3.js

Tags: shiny

```
      # link custom javascript
      tags$head(tags$script(src="www/myscript.js")),
      
      # link custom css, intro.css and c3.css
      tags$head(
        tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "www/custom.css"),
        tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "lib/c3.min.css")
      ),
      
      # link intro.js, d3.js and c3.js
      
      tags$head(tags$script(src="lib/d3.v3.min.js")),
      tags$head(tags$script(src="lib/c3.min.js"))
      
            ),
```

Comment: Hello, can you add a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)? With the information you provided, there's no way to know what the source of the problem is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.